# how to estimate the number of people on a street within an hour?

Tags: statistics

I tried to use opencv to analyze a video filmed on the street. 
But the problem is the performance is not enough.

I think  the number of people must follow the poisson distribution.
So I want to know that is there any statistical method to work out this question?

Comment: What exactly are you counting? People passing through a quiet street?

Comment: What kind of dataset do you want to extract from the video? Do you want to know average no of people during the day? When you talk about performance, what kind of machine are you working on, is there a chance to make the implementation in opencv parallel?